# Interpolating from data

Tags: r, interpolation

Quick question here and I hope it has a quick answer.

This is my [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCP5M.png)

Is there anyway to take an outside list of dates (dates that are not necessarily preexisting data points), and get their corresponding FUEL_PRICE values?

Appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Here is an example of my data:

```
data1
       [date]    [fuel price] 
[1,]  01/15/2010     3.56           
[2,]  01/17/2010     3.32          
[3,]  03/18/2010     3.45           
[4,]  04/20/2010     3.94        
[4,]  04/25/2010     3.94
```

and so on...

Is it possible to then ask what the fuel price would be for 02/15/2010 given the existing data?

Comment: I think you mean extrapolate, not interpolate, since you want to estimate values outside the data range. To do so, you would have to build some regression model and then use that to extrapolate. Using the `lm` function in R is probably the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gaurav. But I am trying to FUEL_PRICE values for dates within 2008 and 2016, but not necessarily dates I already have values for. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `approxfun` will create an interpolation function from data, but it expects numerical data as an input.  I am assuming that your dates are available as strings,  so we need to convert first from strings to dates using `as.POSIXct` then from a date to a number using `as.numeric`.

```
# Sample data
Data = read.table(text= "date    fuel_price 
01/15/2010     3.56           
01/17/2010     3.32          
03/18/2010     3.45           
04/20/2010     3.94        
04/25/2010     3.94", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## Convert date strings to numbers
DateNum = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Data$date, format="%m/%d/%Y"))

## fit a function to the data 
PriceFun = approxfun(Data$fuel_price ~ DateNum)

## Set up a function that will do the same pre-processing on new input. 
PriceFromDate = function(x) {
    round(PriceFun(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x, format="%m/%d/%Y"))), 2) }

## Test with your example
PriceFromDate("02/15/2010 ")
[1] 3.38

## Everything is vectorized so you can give it a list of dates
PriceFromDate(c("02/15/2010 ", "02/20/2010"))
[1] 3.38 3.39
```

To read a csv, estimate the prices and write out the result , you will want something like

```
FuelData = read.csv("YourFile.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  
FuelData$EstPrice = PriceFromDate(FuelData$date)  
write.csv(FuelData, "NewFuelFile.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One quick question though, is there anyway to run a list of dates through the `PriceFromDate` and export the results to a csv?

Comment: Yes,  adding it into the answer

Comment: You're amazing!

Comment: Incredibly sorry, one last question. I am working with a large amount of dates (>1,000,000), so inputting them separately isn't feasible. Can I take an exisiting csv file filed with dates and run them through the function? Then have that function create a new csv file? Again, sorry to bother you!

Comment: Ugly without line feeds.  I will put it into the answer for clean code.
... Now in answer.